# What's the easiest way to make a table in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a table with Python that looks like a simple excel table, therefore I have already used the pyExcelerator. But now I thought about just using `pyplot.table` which seems to be very easy. However, I need to make some changes and I don't know if this is possible in vpyplot.table`.

For example I want to add a cell in the upper left corner and I also want to make two cells beneath the cell `t+1` (see the table example below).

So, is it possible to do these changes in `pyplot.table` or should I better use another way to make tables? [image: table example]

Comment: What format are you trying to create these tables in?  Are you just trying to make an image of your table?  Or do you want output in HTML, or what?

Comment: I just want to make an image of my table to put it in a word-document.

Comment: I'd actually suggest just making an Excel table if you want fancy stuff...

Comment: @MelanieMaza I think CSV is the format you're looking for.

Comment: Please, never include tables in documents that are actually images.

Answer (score -1):

Building a program to generate an table in a image for inclusion into your word document is a bit overkill. Its a lot of added work and completely unnecessary effort. Make the table in Excel and then paste it into Word. It'll look good and will be easier to update and change.

If you are using this as an excuse to learn something new, that is all well and good, but you need to give us more to help you with. SO isn't a code factory. Offer up what you have tried, and samples of code you are having trouble with. We can help with that.